# CHanging the data type from text to date in a column

Tags: sql, mysql, types

i have a table named players_wc where there is a column name Player_DOB whose data type is text.
the values inside the column are like `02-09-1992`. i need to change the data type of the column in order to sort the results on age basis.

```
ALTER TABLE players_wc ADD (DOB DATE);
UPDATE players_wc SET DOB=to_date(Player_DOB,'DD-MM-YYYY');
```

Comment: I think you might be looking for the `STR_TO_DATE` function https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date

Comment: to_date. isn't that Oracle or Postgresql?

Comment: You can find documentation of all the date and time functions for MySQL [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

Comment: Snowflake also has a `TO_DATE()` function, but MySQL does not. You need to understand that every SQL product was developed by different people, and they have implemented different builtin functions. You must check the documentation for the brand and version that you use, to make sure you're using functions correctly. This is how professionals do it!

Answer (score 1):

This might be the expression you're looking for:

```
ALTER TABLE players_wc ADD DOB DATE;
UPDATE players_wc SET DOB = STR_TO_DATE(Player_DOB, '%d-%m-%Y');
```